# Using a 'for' loop. How do I subtract from value 'i' using an if statement?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I am using a script that uses a for loop to spawn objects within Unity. When the player object hits one of these spawned objects it calls a function that makes a boolean true. When this boolean is true it should subtract 1 from the for loop. Basically the for loop has a max of 10, when an object is spawned it adds one, and I want it to subtract 1 when an object is struck by the player. I am having issues trying to make this work. Any and all help, greatly appreciated.

```
var theObject:GameObject;
var maxPos:float = 500;
var minPos:float = -500;
var max = 10;
var switch1 = false;

function Start(){
    StartCoroutine(spawn());
}

function spawn() : IEnumerator {
    for (var i = 0; i < max;){
        if (switch1 == true){
            i--;
        }
        else if (switch1 == false){
            i++;

            //Debug.Log("spawn");
            //Time between spawns
            yield WaitForSeconds(0.4);

            //Determines and spawns new object
            var theNewPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(minPos,maxPos),0,Random.Range(minPos,maxPos));
            var go : GameObject = Instantiate(theObject);
            go.transform.position = theNewPos;
        }
        else{
            switch1 = false;
        }
    }
}

function AtomHit(){
    switch1 = true;
}
```

Comment: switch1 can only be true or false ... so, you don't need `if (switch1 == false)`, just the `else` before it - and the last else will **never** execute

Comment: What issues, exactly, are you having? Be sure to include a [mcve] and a *specific* error. Also, your `if`/`else` logic makes no sense. Look at it: `if (switch1 == true){...} else if (switch1 == false) {...} else {...}`. The second `if` is redundant, and the second `else` can never be reached.

Comment: Is this JavaScript or C#?

Comment: @tengbretson javascript for sure. Functions in C# aren't indicated by `function` keyword, they start with a return type or `void`.

Comment: Can u maybe try to explain what you are trying to achieve here? There might be a better way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do this:?

```
var theObject:GameObject;
var maxPos:float = 500;
var minPos:float = -500;
var max = 10;
var switch1 = false;

function Start(){
    StartCoroutine(spawn());
}

function spawn() : IEnumerator {
    for (var i = 0; i < max;){
        if (switch1){
            i--;
        }
        else{
            i++;

            //Determines and spawns new object
            var theNewPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(minPos,maxPos),0,Random.Range(minPos,maxPos));
            var go : GameObject = Instantiate(theObject);
            go.transform.position = theNewPos;
        }

        //Time between spawns
        yield WaitForSeconds(0.4);
        switch1 = false;
    }
}

function AtomHit(){
    switch1 = true;
}
```